# Launch EXE compiled using MSYS2 with Mintty terminal

Tags: msys2, mintty

I have a GUI application written using GTK that I would like to launch (by double clicking it in Windows File Explorer) with the Mintty terminal used by MSYS2 along with it. This is for debugging purposes with print statements.

If I were in Ubuntu I would use a .desktop file to launch the GUI application with `Terminal=true` set.

Is there an environment variable, compiler flag, or the like that will force the Mintty terminal to come up with the application when it is launched outside of the MSYS2 terminal in Windows?

Comment: Do you specifically need mintty? Any application compiled without `-mwindow` should open its own CMD window.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, any terminal that catches stdout would do. I just added the `-mwindows` flag to the makefile and no terminal appeared when I double clicked the executable.

Comment: You don't need to add the flag. You need to remove it to see the terminal. Perhaps it's getting added by `pkg-config`, or something.

Comment: Ah, I misread that. Apologies. You sent me on the correct path though. The inclusion of `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` in the makefile was the culprit. I have the terminal now. Thanks!